# Not able to utilize web based locators using appium/robotframework

Tags: android, automation, appium, robotframework, saucelabs

I am trying to utilize RIDE and Robot framework with appium for mobile testing and I am unable to get appium/sauce to recognize the locators we used for our browser platform testing. It is a web based app so all of the locators should be the same and I am unsure of the syntax required for RIDE to utilize the appium library. I have added the sauce log as well as what I currently have in robot framework. We are able to get the app loaded, the login screen loaded and then fail out when it tries to input a login name/password.

https://saucelabs.com/tests/1b762e1a7d2f4fc694bd0957f7d0d1b1

appiumlibrary.open application  http://test@localhost:4445/wd/hub   platformName=android platformVersion=5.0\appiumversion=1.4 \    deviceName=android emulator app=test-url.apk device-orientation=portrait

sleep   30
Input Text  xpath=//*[@id=login-inner]  test

Input Text  //*[@test-id='fldPassword'] test

Click Element   //*[@class='ember-view pointer login-btn logon-submit btn btn-primary submitButton form-validation-submit submit is-valid']

Comment: What is the error that you get when the test fails?

Comment: in RIDE I am getting a did not match any elements value error.
Sauce is returning a few different things in the appium log here
https://saucelabs.com/tests/1b762e1a7d2f4fc694bd0957f7d0d1b1

I have tried multiple locators as well such as test-id, id, etc.